# Display next array items on click

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop

I tried to write a click function to display next array items on click function in jquery but it did not work. Please advice:)

```js
  var array = [one, two, three, four, five];
  
  $('#countButton').click(function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
         $('#displayCount').html(array[i++]);        
        }       
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />
<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Comment: do not loop. store your counter outside the click event and increase it after you set the html

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary to use a loop here. Just access the next element in your array after you click:

```
  var array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  var count = 0;
  $('#countButton').click(function(){
    if(count <= array.length){
      count++;
    } else{ 
      count = 0
    }
    $('#displayCount').html(array[count]);                 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to loop it. just have a global variable use the same increment method

```js
var array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
var i = 0;
$('#countButton').click(function() {
  $('#displayCount').html(array[i++%5]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="button" value="Count" id="countButton" />
<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Comment: What happens when i becomes greater than the array size? It'll break

Comment: Check now. Now it will again start from one. You can change it how ever you want, its so flexible

Comment: What `[i++%5]` mean. I know `i++` but I do not know `%5`.

Comment: It is modulo operation which will get the remainder by dividing with 5

Comment: I see but why do I need to use it?

Comment: You dont need to, If you want only these five numbers then you can loop through them. otherwise just have the full array

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/342523) and [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/342523) if it is working